# How to convert array of objects to key value pair javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, import

Here I want to convert the data from JSON file into a object of key value pair.

Example -

```
[
    {
        "name": "qwerty0",
        "family": "group0",
        "age": 0,
        "address": "XYZ0"
    },
    {
        "name": "qwerty1",
        "family": "group1",
        "age": 1,
        "address": "XYZ1"
    } 
]
```

should look like the below after importing-

```
    {
        "name": "qwerty0",
        "family": "group0",
        "age": 0,
        "address": "XYZ0"
    },
    {
        "name": "qwerty1",
        "family": "group1",
        "age": 1,
        "address": "XYZ1"
    }
```

Comment: I don't see any difference apart from the missing `[]`.

Comment: Is it actual JSON or an array of objects? If an array, you would simply access it by its index `variableName[0]`. If JSON, parse it, then use the index.

Comment: What  do you want is not a valid json. Pls review your post.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Try using JSON.parse function

```
listOfObjects = JSON.parse(jsonFile)

//Now you can select the objects from the list

[object1, object2] = listOfObjects
```